# Rename [metroid-prime-3] → [metroid-prime-3-corruption]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for Metroid Prime 3: Corruption from [metroid-prime-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metroid-prime-3) to [metroid-prime-3-corruption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metroid-prime-3-corruption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've renamed it to [metroid-prime-3-corruption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metroid-prime-3-corruption).